# Why can't I install angr-z3 using pip on Windows when Python is 64-bit?

Tags: python, pip, 64-bit, z3, angr

It says the module machine type doesn't match; why?
<sub>*(Note: This is a self-answered question; see below.)*</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `setup.py` needs to pass the `-x` flag to `mk_make.py` in order to build in 64-bit mode, but isn't doing so. You can solve this by downloading and extracting the package yourself, then changing line 28 in `setup.py` from

```
        if subprocess.call([sys.executable, os.path.join(build_dir,
                                                         'scripts',
                                                         'mk_make.py')],
```

to

```
        if subprocess.call([sys.executable, os.path.join(build_dir,
                                                         'scripts',
                                                         'mk_make.py'), '-x'],
```